# iAds suddenly stopped showing on iPads, but still appear on iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

iAds in our iOS app used to appear on both iPads and iPhones. However, they stopped displaying on iPads recently, and we have no clue why. We didn't change any of the advertising code. Did Apple change the policy around apps that are not optimized for iPads? Our app is not universal, meaning you see it at iPhone size on iPads. Thanks.

The app works on devices with iOS 5.1+.